# Semantic of empty shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reference-counting, nullptr

I've noticed a strange fact about shared_ptr

```
int* p = nullptr;
std::shared_ptr<int> s(p); // create a count (1).
std::shared_ptr<int> s2(s); // count go to 2.
assert(s.use_count() == 2);
```

I wonder what is the semantic beyond this. Why are s and s2 sharing a nullptr ? Does it makes any sense ?

Or maybe this uncommon situation doesn't deserve a if statement (costly ?) ?

Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: AFAICT, it doesn't make a difference whether it's null or whether it's a valid object, so why should it care?

Comment: I don't suppose reference counting pointers have special handling for nullptr.

Comment: In C++11, `use_count()` must be `0` on empty `shared_ptr`'s (20.7.2.2.5/7).

Comment: See also [Defect Report 813](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantics are:

- If you default-construct a shared pointer, or construct one from `nullptr_t`, it's empty; that is, it doesn't own any pointer.
- If you construct one from a raw pointer, it takes ownership of that pointer, whether or not it's null. I guess that's done for the reason you mention (avoiding a runtime check), but I can only speculate about that.

So your example isn't empty; it owns a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it doesn't matter. By the way, the reference counter allocation is quite more expensive than a runtime check (but this situation is certainly less frequent).

Answer (score 1):

Who cares that they are sharing the `nullptr`? As soon as they are both destroyed, they will attempt to `delete nullptr;` which will have no effect. That's perfectly okay and fits in with the semantics of `shared_ptr`.

It makes sense in the way that no special case is required for null pointer values. Whether it occurs in your code just comes down to whether you have some function that can take or return null `shared_ptr`s.

Answer (score 0):

shared_ptr will count and free whatever pointer it was given(not only nullptr, but something invalid as well). so in your example this will end up with nullptr being deleted which is valid case.
[Is it still safe to delete nullptr in c++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731331/is-it-still-safe-to-delete-nullptr-in-c0x)