# C++ memory access error

Tags: c++, memory

I've got a problem when trying to call a function Organization::addWorker, it seems to fail on a memory deallocation step, an operator delete[], but the memory have already been freed which the pointer shows to.

call stack:

> lab1.exe!Person::setName(char * thename)Line 80 C++
>
> lab1.exe!Coworker::operator=(Coworker & theco)Line 303  C++
>
> lab1.exe!Organization::addWorker(Coworker & theworker)Line 404  C++
>
> lab1.exe!main()Line 97  C++

```
   #include <string>
    #include "class_Date.h"
    
    using namespace std;
    
    enum workNec { worker, manager, employer };
    
    class Person {
    
        char* name; 
        char* surname;
        Date bd;
    
    public:
    
        Person();
        Person(char* thename, char* thesurname, Date thebd);
        Person(const Person &theperson);
        ~Person();
    
        char* getName() { return name; }
        char* getSurname() { return surname; }
        Date getBD() { return bd; }
    
        void getFullInfo();
    
        Person & setName(char* thename);
        Person & setSurname(char* thesurname);
        Person & setBD(int dd, int mm, int yy);
        Person & setBD(Date thebd);
    
        Person & operator=(Person& thepers);
    
    };
    
    Person::Person() { 
    
        name = new char [1];
        strcpy(name, "");
        surname = new char[1];
        strcpy(surname, "");
    
    }
    
    Person::Person(char* thename, char* thesurname, Date thebd) { 
    
        name = new char [strlen(thename)+1];
        surname = new char [strlen(thesurname)+1];
        strcpy(name, thename);
        strcpy(surname, thesurname);
        bd = thebd;
    
    }
    Person::Person(const Person & theperson) { 
    
        name = new char[strlen(theperson.name) + 1];
        surname = new char[strlen(theperson.surname) + 1];
        strcpy(name, theperson.name);
        strcpy(surname, theperson.surname);
        bd = theperson.bd;
    
    }
    Person::~Person() {
    
        cout << "Destructing Person " << name << endl;
        delete [] name;
        delete [] surname;
    
    
    }
    
    void Person::getFullInfo() { 
        
        cout << name << " " << surname << " "; bd.getFullDate(); 
    
    }
    
    Person & Person::setName(char* thename)  { 
    
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[strlen(thename) + 1]; strcpy(name, thename); 
        return *this; 
    
    }
    
    Person & Person::setSurname(char* thesurname) { 
        
        delete [] surname;
        surname = new char[strlen(thesurname) + 1]; strcpy(surname, thesurname);
        return *this; 
    
    }
    Person & Person::setBD(int dd, int mm, int yy) { 
        
        bd.setDD(dd); bd.setMM(mm); bd.setYY(yy); 
        return *this; 
    
    }
    
    Person & Person::setBD(Date thebd) { 
    
        bd = thebd; 
        return *this; 
    
    }
    
    Person & Person::operator=(Person& thepers) {
    
        delete [] this->name;
        delete [] this->surname;
        this->name = new char[strlen(thepers.name) + 1];
        this->surname = new char[strlen(thepers.surname) + 1];
        strcpy(this->name, thepers.name);
        strcpy(this->surname, thepers.surname);
        bd = thepers.bd;
        return *this;
    }
    
    //*************************************************************************************************
    
    class Position {
    
        char* department;
        workNec wn;
        int salary;
    
    public:
    
        Position();
        Position(char *thedept, workNec thewn, int thesalary);
        Position(const Position & thepos);
        ~Position();
    
        char* getDept() { return department; }
        workNec getWorkNec() { return wn; }
        int getSalary() { return salary; }
    
        void getFullInfo();
    
        Position & setDept(char* dept);
        Position & setWorkNec(workNec nec);
        Position & setSalary(int sal);
    
    };
    
    
    Position::Position() {
    
        department = new char[1];
        strcpy(department, "");
    
    }
    
    Position::Position(char *thedept, workNec thewn, int thesalary) { 
    
        department = new char[strlen(thedept) + 1];
        strcpy(department, thedept);
        wn = thewn; 
        salary = thesalary; 
    
    }
    
    Position::Position(const Position & thepos) { 
    
        department = new char[strlen(thepos.department)+1]; 
        strcpy(department, thepos.department);
        wn = thepos.wn; 
        salary = thepos.salary; 
    
    }
    
    Position::~Position() { 
    
        cout << endl << "Deleting Position " << department << endl;
        delete [] department;
    
    }
    
    void Position::getFullInfo() { 
        
        cout << department << " " << wn << " " << salary << " "; 
    
    }
    
    Position & Position::setDept(char* dept) { 
    
        delete [] department;
        department = new char[strlen(dept)+1];
        strcpy(department, dept);
        return *this; 
    
    }
    Position & Position::setWorkNec(workNec nec) {
        
        wn = nec; 
        return *this; 
    
    }
    Position & Position::setSalary(int sal) { 
        
        salary = sal; 
        return *this; 
    
    }
    
    //*************************************************************************************************
    
    class Coworker {
    
        Person person;
        Position position;
    
    public:
    
        Coworker();
        Coworker(Person &theperson, Position &thepos);
        Coworker( Coworker & theco);
        ~Coworker();
    
        Person getPerson() { return person; }
        Position getPosition() { return position; }
    
        void getFullInfo();
    
        Coworker & setPerson(Person &per);
        Coworker & setPosition(Position &pos);
    
        Coworker & operator=(Coworker& theco);
        
    };
    
    Coworker::Coworker() {
    
    }
    
    Coworker::Coworker(Person &theperson, Position &thepos) { 
        
        person.setBD(theperson.getBD());
        person.setName(theperson.getName());
        person.setSurname(theperson.getSurname());
        position.setDept(thepos.getDept());
        position.setSalary(thepos.getSalary());
        position.setWorkNec(thepos.getWorkNec());
    
    }
    
    Coworker::Coworker(Coworker & theco) { 
    
        Person pers;
        pers = theco.person;
        Position pos = theco.position;
    
        person.setBD(pers.getBD());
        person.setName(pers.getName());
        person.setSurname(pers.getSurname());
        position.setDept(pos.getDept());
        position.setSalary(pos.getSalary());
        position.setWorkNec(pos.getWorkNec());
    
    }
    
    Coworker::~Coworker() {
    
    
        cout << endl << "Deleting Coworker " << endl;
    
    }
    
    void Coworker::getFullInfo() { 
        
        person.getFullInfo(); cout << " ";  position.getFullInfo(); 
    
    }
    
    Coworker & Coworker::setPerson(Person &per) { 
        
        Person tper = per;
        person.setBD(tper.getBD());
        person.setName(tper.getName());
        person.setSurname(tper.getSurname());
        return *this; 
    
    }
    Coworker & Coworker::setPosition(Position &pos) { 
        
        Position tpos = pos;
        position.setDept(tpos.getDept());
        position.setSalary(tpos.getSalary());
        position.setWorkNec(tpos.getWorkNec());
        return *this; 
    
    }
    
    Coworker & Coworker::operator=(Coworker& theco) {
    
        Person pers;
        pers = theco.person;
        Position pos;
        pos = theco.position;
    
        person.setBD(pers.getBD());
        person.setName(pers.getName());
        person.setSurname(pers.getSurname());
        position.setDept(pos.getDept());
        position.setSalary(pos.getSalary());
        position.setWorkNec(pos.getWorkNec());
        return *this;
    }
    
    class Organization {
    
        char* title;
        Coworker * coworker;
        int cwAmount;
    
    public:
    
        Organization();
        Organization(char* thetitle, Coworker * theco, int thecw);
        Organization(const Organization & org);
        ~Organization();
    
        void addWorker(Coworker &theworker);
    
        char* getTitle() { return title; }
        int getAmount() { return cwAmount; }
        Coworker * getCoworker() { return coworker; }
    
        Organization & setTitle(char* tit);
        Organization & setAmount(int am);
        Organization & setCoworker(Coworker *theco);
    
        void getFullInfo();
        void getShortInfo();
    
    };
    
    //*************************************************************************************************
    
    Organization::Organization() {
    
        title = new char[1];
        strcpy(title, "");
        cwAmount = 0;
        coworker = new Coworker[0];
    
    }
    
    
    Organization::Organization(char* thetitle, Coworker * theco, int thecw) { 
        
        title = new char[strlen(thetitle) + 1];
        strcpy(title, thetitle);
    
        cwAmount = thecw; 
        coworker = new Coworker[cwAmount];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) {
    
            coworker[i].setPerson(theco[i].getPerson());
            coworker[i].setPosition(theco[i].getPosition());
    
        }
    
    }
    
    Organization::Organization(const Organization & org) { 
        
        title = new char[strlen(org.title) + 1];
        strcpy(title, org.title);
    
        cwAmount = org.cwAmount; 
    
        coworker = new Coworker[cwAmount];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) {
    
            coworker[i].setPerson(org.coworker[i].getPerson());
            coworker[i].setPosition(org.coworker[i].getPosition());
    
        }
    
    }
    
    Organization::~Organization() { 
        
    
        cout << endl << "Deleting Organization " <<title<< endl;
        delete [] coworker;
    
    };
    
    void Organization::addWorker(Coworker &theworker) {
        cout << "a";
    
        Coworker * new_coworker = new Coworker[cwAmount + 1];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) new_coworker[i] = coworker[i];
    
        cwAmount++;
    
        new_coworker[cwAmount] = theworker;
    
        delete [] coworker;
    
        coworker = new_coworker;
    
    }
    
    void Organization::getFullInfo() {
    
        std::cout << title << " " << cwAmount << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) {
            coworker[i].getPerson().getFullInfo();
            cout << " ";
            coworker[i].getPosition().getFullInfo();
            cout << endl;
        }
    
    }
    
    void Organization::getShortInfo() {
    
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) {
    
            total += coworker[i].getPosition().getSalary();
    
        }
    
        std::cout << this->title << " " << total << std::endl;
    
    }
    
    Organization & Organization::setTitle(char* tit) { 
        
        title = new char[strlen(tit)+1]; 
        strcpy(title, tit);
        return *this; 
    
    }
    
    Organization & Organization::setAmount(int am) { 
        
        cwAmount = am; 
        return *this; 
    }
    
    Organization & Organization::setCoworker(Coworker *theco) { 
    
        delete [] coworker;
        coworker = new Coworker [cwAmount];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) {
    
            coworker[i].setPerson(theco[i].getPerson());
            coworker[i].setPosition(theco[i].getPosition());
    
        }
    
        return *this; 
    
    }
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "classes_v23.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    {
    Date d1;

    Date d2(19, 04, 1995);

    Date d3 = d2;

    d1.getFullDate(); cout << endl;
    d2.getFullDate(); cout << endl;
    d3.getFullDate(); cout << endl;

    //******************************

    Person pers1;

    pers1.setBD(d2);
    pers1.setName("Ihor");
    pers1.setSurname("Pukish");

    Person pers2("name2", "surname2", d2);
    Person pers3 = pers2;

    pers1.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;
    pers2.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;
    pers3.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;

    //******************************

    Position pos1;

    pos1.setDept("IASA");
    pos1.setSalary(100);
    pos1.setWorkNec(employer);

    Position pos2("dept2", worker, 200);
    Position pos3 = pos2;

    pos1.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;
    pos2.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;
    pos3.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;

    //******************************

    Coworker co1;
    co1.setPerson(pers1);
    co1.setPosition(pos1);

    Coworker co2(pers2, pos2);
    Coworker co3 = co2;
    Coworker co4(pers1, pos1);

    co1.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;
    co2.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;
    co3.getFullInfo(); cout << endl;

    //******************************

    Coworker * cow = new Coworker[3];
    cow[0] = co1;
    cow[1] = co2;
    cow[2] = co3;

    Organization org1("title", cow, 3);
    org1.addWorker(co4);
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You missed several `operator=`. Your `operator=` do not support `a=a`. You should be using `std::string`.

Comment: I just want to comment that I like the way, you organize your code...that aside, i wish you showed the line numbers...if you can point out to what line the error is coming from it would be helpful...

Comment: I suggest that if are are going to use the char arrays that after using `delete` you should assign NULL or 0 or nullptr  to the pointer variable. [what exactly is nullptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) and see [is it still save to delete nullptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731331/is-it-still-safe-to-delete-nullptr-in-c0x)

Comment: @Dark Falcon , the task requires to use only pointer to char array, not strings. I seem not to need more operators "=" than i used. Or am I mistaken? And where do i need using my operator for "a=a"?

Comment: @ІгорПукіш: You need more. You need them on every class that has a `char*` member in it (and they are missing in `Position` and `Organization`). The compiler-generated one does NOT work. This is why I recommended using `std::string`; with it the compiler-generated one does work.

Comment: Person::~Person() {

        cout << "Destructing Person " << name << endl;
        delete [] name;
        delete [] surname;
        name = NULL;
        surname = NULL;
    } -- i tried, it doesn't help

Comment: @ІгорПукіш: Regarding the `a=a`, you probably don't actually do that in this program, but you should be in the habit of supporting it in case someone using your code does it. Your current `operator=` implementations delete the source string. You need to add a check to make sure the source and destination are not the same.

Comment: @DarkFalcon , {...name = new char [strlen(thename)+1];
        surname = new char [strlen(thesurname)+1];
        strcpy(name, thename);
        strcpy(surname, thesurname);...} --- i thought this way of copying could go without using operator=

Comment: this is the string in the addWorker() function, which causes an error. new_coworker[cwAmount] = theworker;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is:

```
void Organization::addWorker(Coworker &theworker) {
    cout << "a";

    Coworker * new_coworker = new Coworker[cwAmount + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < cwAmount; i++) new_coworker[i] = coworker[i];

    cwAmount++;

    new_coworker[cwAmount] = theworker;

    delete [] coworker;

    coworker = new_coworker;

}
```

Notice that you increment `cwAmount` before assigning `theworker`.  However I think you should assign first, then increment.  The empty element is located at the pre-increment index.

This could also be done much easier using a vector.

Comment: yeah, uou are right. I used the index of an array that does not in a range. Don't know how i didn.t notice it.

Comment: Thank everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

First, you included `<string>`, but you failed to use what `<string>` has to offer, namely `std::string`.  Since you say you must use C-style strings, the correct header is `<cstring>`, not `<string>`.

Second, this function will not work if NULL is passed, or even a bogus pointer:

```
Person::Person(char* thename, char* thesurname, Date thebd) { 
        name = new char [strlen(thename)+1];   // undefined behavior if NULL is passed
        surname = new char [strlen(thesurname)+1];  // undefined behavior if NULL is passed
        //...
    }
```

That function should be checking for NULL pointer argumemts.  But even with that, there is a risk of being passed a pointer that isn't pointing to a valid buffer.

Now, as others stated, you need to write your assignment operator correctly and for every class that has pointers to dynamically allocated memory.

Let's start with the `Person` assignment operator:

```
 Person & Person::operator=(Person& thepers) {
        delete [] this->name;
        delete [] this->surname;
        this->name = new char[strlen(thepers.name) + 1];
        this->surname = new char[strlen(thepers.surname) + 1];
        strcpy(this->name, thepers.name);
        strcpy(this->surname, thepers.surname);
        bd = thepers.bd;
        return *this;
    }
```

Not only is this redundant (most of this code is in the copy constructor), it fails for the following reasons:

1. You `delete[]` the name and surname.  What happens if the following `new[]` throws an exception?  You've messed up your object by deleting your data before you could be assured that new wouldn't fail.
2. You don't check for self-assignment.
3. The item should be passed as a const reference.

The way to fix is simple, and I suggest you do that for all of your other classes.

```
 #include <algorithm>
 //...
 Person & Person::operator=(const Person& thepers) 
 {
      Person other(thepers);
      swap(*this, other);
      return *this;
 }

 void Person::swap(Person& left, Person& right)
 {
      std::swap(left.name, right.name);
      std::swap(left.surname, right.surname);
      std::swap(left.bd, right.bd);
  }
```

That's it, nothing else.  This is called the `copy/swap` idiom.  As long as you have coded a working and correct copy constructor, the code above not only copies correctly, it gets rid of the issues of self-assignment, and destroying members prematurely.

The way it works is to create a temporary, "steal" the temporary's stuff for your own by swapping yours with the temporary's , and have the temporary die, along with your old stuff.  That in layman's terms is what is happening.

Please do this for the other classes.  For example, `Coworker`:

```
Coworker & Coworker::operator=(const Coworker& theco) 
{
   Coworker temp(theco);
   swap(*this, temp);
   return *this;
}

void Coworker::swap(Coworker& left, Coworker& right)
{
    std::swap(left.person, right.person);
    std::swap(left.position, right.position);
}
```

In addition, your `Organization` class is missing an assignment operator.  Just add one by using the above techniques.

Also, your `setName` function also suffers from deletion of memory before reallocation:

```
Person & Person::setName(char* thename)  { 
    delete [] name;
    name = new char[strlen(thename) + 1]; strcpy(name, thename); 
    return *this; 
}
```

This can also be alleviated by allocating to a temporary first, and then assigning the 
temporary at the end of the function:

```
Person & Person::setName(char* thename)  
{ 
    char *tempname = new char[strlen(thename) + 1]; 
    strcpy(tempname, thename); 
    delete [] name;
    name = tempname;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: thanks for tips, they are pretty useful. The only thing is that i am not allowed to use the outside functions, e.g. swap, and so on, cause it is only introducing lab.

Comment: @ІгорПукіш You can't use "outside functions", but you're using `strcpy()` and `strlen()` which are "outside" function.

Comment: i mean i can't use different method in my class, only which where mentioned.