# Virtual function doesn't work for 1 class, but works for another

Tags: c++

My program has the following structure: class **Core** is the base class, class **Grad** inherits Core and class **Pass_fail** inherits Core. Class **Student_info** just manages pointers to these classes and create appropriate object at the run-time according to users' needs. The problem: classes Core, Grad and Pass_fail have a virtual function called grade(). Every class calculates the grade in its own way. When the program calls grade() with Core or Grad objects, it works just fine. But when the program calls grade() for Pass_fail obj, virtual mechanism doesn't work and instead Core.grade() function is called.

Class Core:

```
class Core {
    friend class Student_info;
public:
    Core() : midterm(0), final(0) { std::cerr << "Core obj created" << std::endl; }
    Core(std::istream& is);

    std::string name() const;

    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream&);
    virtual double grade() const;
    virtual bool valid() const;
    virtual bool did_req() const;

    virtual ~Core() {  }
protected:
    virtual Core* clone() const { return new Core(*this); }
    std::istream& read_common(std::istream&);
    std::istream& read_hw(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homework;
private:
    std::string n;
};
```

Class Grad:

```
class Grad : public Core {
public:
    Grad() : thesis(0) { std::cerr << "Grad obj created" << std::endl; }
    Grad(std::istream& is);

    double grade() const;
    std::istream& read(std::istream&);
    bool did_req() const;
protected:
    Grad* clone() const { return new Grad(*this); }
private:
    double thesis;
};
```

Class Pass_fail:

```
class Pass_fail : public Core
{
public:
    Pass_fail() { std::cerr << "Pass_fail obj created" << std::endl; }
    Pass_fail(std::istream&);
    std::istream& read(std::istream&);

    double grade() const;
    //bool did_req() const;
protected:
    Pass_fail* clone() { return new Pass_fail(*this); }
};
```

Pass_fail grade function:

```
double Pass_fail::grade() const
{
    std::cerr << "Pass_fail grade() function" << std::endl;
    if (valid())
        return Core::grade();
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Homework is empty" << std::endl;
        return (midterm + final) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Class Student_info (manages pointers):

```
class Student_info {
public:
    Student_info(): cp(0) { }
    Student_info(std::istream& is) : cp(0) { read(is); }
    Student_info(const Student_info&);
    Student_info& operator=(const Student_info&);
    ~Student_info() { delete cp; }

    std::istream& read(std::istream&);
    bool valid() { return cp->valid(); }
    bool did_req() { return cp->did_req(); }

    std::string name() const
    {
        if (cp) return cp->name();
        else throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized student");
    }
    double grade() const
    {
        if (cp) return cp->grade();
        else throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized student");
    }
    static bool compare(const Student_info& s1, const Student_info& s2)
    {
        return s1.name() < s2.name();
    }

private:
    Core* cp;
};
```

A piece of main():

```
...
vector<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
...
...
while (record.read(cin))
    {

        students.push_back(record);
    }
....
double final_grade = students[i].grade(); \\ the problem is here-> Core.grade() func is called instead of Pass_fail.grade()
```

Comment: In student info, you need to check for null in the destructor before deleting. (Not related to your issue, but important, too)

Comment: the author of the book said it's safe to delete null pointer

Comment: That's a difficult topic. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6731331/1116364 It probably is safe, but you can't be 100% sure. Best would be to not use a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, `clone()` is not `const` in `Pass_fail`, that's why the virtual mechanism didn't work.

`Student_info` copy constructor yielded every time I did `students.push_back(record)`. Since `clone()` was not overriden in `Pass_fail` class, wrong `clone()` was yielded and as a result wrong `grade()`