# Delete objects from a singleton class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I want to create a simple Singleton class in C++ which contains pointers to other types.

The singleton will become the owner over that pointer at some point.

So it's this a good way to delete the object of type Test and release it's memory on Singleton destructor?.

```
 class Test{...};
 class Singleton
 {
    public:
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> instance(new Singleton());
        return *instance.get();
    }

    void SetTest(Test* test);
    Test* GetTest() const;
    ...
    private:
      Singleton(){}
      ~Singleton(){ if(test) delete test;} // ??
      Test* test;
     ...
 };
```

PS: I can't use smart pointers for the Test object.

Comment: i guess you meant "pointer to objects of other type", afaik there is no pointer to a type

Comment: You should probably initialize `test` in the constructor. Otherwise if the user never calls `SetTest` then `GetTest` will return an invalid (and most likely non-null) pointer, and the destructor will attempt to delete something which wasn't allocated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a singleton is anti-pattern. And anything you need it to own is probably indicative of greater anti-patterns in your code.

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps using pointers for the member variables is not the correct thing to do? Perhaps use plain objects instead? And if you need to use pointers (due to some other requirement), then perhaps use `std::unique_ptr` for them too?

Comment: Test is forwarded declared so that's why I can't use smart pointers

Comment: With a custom deleter it's still possible to use smart pointers.

Comment: shared_ptr<> does not need a complete type ( but shared_ptr dtor does ), no need of a custom deleter

Comment: moreover, "if(test) delete test;" is useless ( you can delete a null pointer ) ...

Comment: I don't understand.  Usually, a singleton lasts forever.  The memory allocated to a singleton will be recovered after the program exits.  Why would you need to delete objects inside a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give this question some conclusion: Yes, it generally fine to delete the object like you propose. However, please mind the following caveats, that have already been pointed out in the comments:

- Make sure to initialize `test` to `nullptr` in the constructor of the singleton. Otherwise you might end up trying to delete a random memory address. (Some programmer dude)
- You don't need to check for `nullptr` in the destructor. Deleting a `nullptr` is generally safe and won't do anything. (Massimiliano Janes and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731331/is-it-still-safe-to-delete-nullptr-in-c0x))
- It is probably possible to use a smart pointer in your case, which would be preferable. (Some programmer dude, Massimiliano Janes)