# emplace_back and push_back give 'double free or corruption (fasttop)' error although copy and move constructor are defined

Tags: c++, vector, destructor, move-constructor

I am just tipping my toes into C++ and probably missing something obvious here. I have a class that dynamically allocates an array and I would like to put its objects into a vector. Since the array has to be freed in the destructor and it is called by `vector.push_back()` I read that I have to define a copy- as well as move-constructor to avoid memory corruption errors. However, the example below still gives me a `double free or corruption (fasttop)` error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class bla {
  public:
    int* arr;

    bla() {
        arr = new int[10];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arr[i] = 42;
        }
    }

    bla(bla&& b) : arr(b.arr) {
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }

    bla(const bla& b) : arr(b.arr) {
        cout << "copy" << endl;
    }

    ~bla() {
        cout << "delete" << endl;
        delete[] arr;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<bla> blas;
    blas.reserve(5000);

    blas.push_back(bla());          // same result with emplace_back
    blas.push_back(bla());          // same result with emplace_back
    blas.push_back(bla());          // same result with emplace_back

    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong and maybe also provide an example of how to add objects with dynamic memory to vectors (I know that I can use pointers, but from what I read it should also work with the objects themselves).

I run `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609` with `-Wall -std=c++11 -lm`

**UPDATE 1:**
Running the same code with the same flags on `g++ 7.4.0` does not result in the double free error. Does anybody have an idea why?

**UPDATE 2:**
For posterity, since apparently there are not that many minimal examples implementing the rule of 5 for dynamic arrays floating around. This is how you should do it (please correct me, if I'm wrong):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class bla {
public:
int* arr;

bla()
    : arr(nullptr)
{
    arr = new int[10];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = 42;
    }
}

~bla() {
    cout << "delete" << endl;
    delete[] arr;
}

// deep copy constructor
bla(const bla& other) {
    cout << "copy" << endl;
    arr = new int[10];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = other.arr[i];
    }
}

// deep copy assignment
bla& operator = (const bla& other) {
    cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
    if (&other != this) {
        delete[] arr;
        arr = new int[10];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arr[i] = other.arr[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

// move constructor
bla(bla&& other)
    : arr(other.arr) {
    cout << "move" << endl;
    other.arr = nullptr;
}

// move assignment
bla& operator = (bla&& other){
    cout << "move assignment" << endl;
    if(&other != this) {
        delete[] arr;
        arr = other.arr;
        other.arr = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}
};

int main() {
    vector<bla> blas;

    cout << "=========\nstart pushs\n=========" << endl;

    blas.push_back(bla());
    blas.push_back(bla());
    blas.push_back(bla());

    cout << endl << "=========\nend pushs\n=========" << endl << endl;;

    cout << "for each:" << endl;
    for (bla b : blas) {
        cout << b.arr[0] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "native for:" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << blas[i].arr[0] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your move ctor isn't clearing `b`. Also you're missing assignment operators.

Comment: But in general, you're better off using a `unique_ptr` rather than a raw pointer for your member. The rule of 0 is preferred over the rule of 5.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. After doing more research on the rules of 3/5/0 I now understand how to implement something like this properly. However, running the faulty code on a newer compiler does not yield the same error, although specifying the same standard. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read that I have to define a copy- as well as move-constructor to
>   avoid memory corruption errors.

That is true, but they also need to do the right thing. Not just any copy/move constructor will do the job; and both the copy constructor and the move constructor here have the same flaw. Using the copy constructor as an example:

```
bla(const bla& b) : arr(b.arr) {
```

So, if you work out what happens here with a piece of paper and pencil, after copy construction takes place both the new object and this original object, `b`, will have the same `arr` pointer. Because that's exactly what this code does.

So, when both objects get destroyed, their destructor will attempt to `delete[]` the same exact pointer. Both `b` and the same object have the same `arr`. There's your double-free.

Same problem occurs with the move constructor.

Also, the shown class does not have an explicit assignment or a move-assignment operator. So, assigning one of these objects to another one will: 1) end up leaking the overwritten object's `arr`, 2) end up with two objects having the same `arr`, and the same problem, when they get eventually get destroyed.

In the case of a copy constructor you don't have any option other than making a copy of the copied-from `arr`, and its values. In the case of a move constructor you do have the option of just setting `b.arr` to `nullptr`. The destructor will then [quietly ignore `delete[]`ion of a `nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731331/is-it-still-safe-to-delete-nullptr-in-c0x); although it's often considered good practice to explicit check for a `nullptr`, before `delete[]`ing it.

You will also need to implement a proper `operator=` overload (just a regular assignment with an optional move-assignment), in order to fix the same problem.

Comment: deleting a nullptr is defined behavior in C++ (as a noop), I wouldn't necessarily advertise that it is good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added an improved example to the question, is this the right way to do it?