QVBoxLayout::count not returning 0 after cleaning it
I have a QVBoxLayout that is cleared at runtime on some event this way:
void OnSomeEvent()
{
   while(!(UiPtr->VLayout->isEmpty()))
   {
      QLayoutItem* child = UiPtr->VLayout->takeAt(0);
      delete child->widget();
      delete child;
   }

   bool isEmpty = UiPtr->VLayout->isEmpty(); // This returns true, which is expected

   int count = UiPtr->VLayout->count(); // This returns 1, I was expecting it to return 0
}

This does clear the layout, it seems, because the layout becomes visibly empty.
But, why is count returning 1?

I think that isEmpty might be doing something counter-intuitive. It's a method of QLayoutItem and it tells if "it contains any widgets". So, if e.g. you simply construct a layout QVBoxLayout v; and add some widget to it v.addWidget(new QPushButton), it is still empty. Try to reimplement your loop with count() condition.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4857631/4165552 with recursive solution, but you can achieve the same without recursion.

@pptaszni
Implementing loop count api did work. Thanks !

This question is similar to: Clearing a Layout in Qt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
